Solving an exponential equation without differentiation
$$2x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}=2^{1-x^2}$$
We can solve this by considering the maximum and the minimum of RHS and LHS.
So we have $x=1$ as the answer.
Are there other methods to solve this equation without maximum minimum?

Do you mean $x = \pm 1$?

Could you define RHS and LHS?

$2 x^2 - 1/x^2$ has no maximum or minimum, so I don't know what maximum and minimum you mean.  But you might note that $2 x^2 - 1/x^2$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$ while $2^{1-x^2}$ is decreasing there, so there is only one positive solution.

@DEMB - "right hand side" and "left hand side" (of an equation).

I doubt this equation can be solved algebraically without invoking or defining Lambert-like functions. Moreover, note that the right- and left-hand side don't possess any extrema, because they are monotone functions. Nevertheless, this equation can be treated with the procedure detailed below.
Firstly, given that both sides are even, we may set $t := x^2$ and restrict ourselves to the positive values, i.e. $t \ge 0$. We also define the functions $f(t) = 2t-\frac{1}{t}$ and $g(t) = 2^{1-t}$. The function $f(t)$ turns out to increase monotonically, because $f'(t) = 2 + \frac{1}{t^2} > 0$, from to $f(0) = -\infty$ to $f(\infty) = \infty$, while $g(t)$ decreases monotonically from $g(0) = 2$ to $g(\infty) = 0$, because $g'(t) = -2^{1-t}\ln2 < 0$.
In consequence, the graphs of $f$ and $g$ must intersect only once, somewhere between 0 and 2 on the $y$-axis. By inspection, we see that $f(t) = g(t)$ at $t = 1$, as you found. This allows us to conclude that the solutions are given by $x = \pm1$ and nothing else.
